# Change volume from bash

Tags: bash, audio, alsa

I got this far (from `.bashrc`):

```
alias i="amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback +1dB"
alias d="amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback -1dB"
alias v4="amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback 40%"
alias v8="amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback 80%"
```

The first two rows should work, if I read the `man amixer` page correctly, and they don't produce an error message, but their behavior is unreliable: sometimes there's a huge change, most often nothing happens.

The last two rows work. I guess you could make like ten aliases. Still, you would like the increase/decrease functionality to bind to keyboard shortcuts.

Am I using `amixer` the wrong way or is there some other tool to do the trick? (`alsamixer` doesn't seem to have this functionality as CLI commands.)

**Edit**

At last, made it work. This was so long ago (how sad!), so I have lost track of who contributed what. Anyway, thanks. (Below: For bash users, put in `.bashrc`)

```
# volume
alias vol="alsamixer"
MASTER="amixer -q -c 0 sset Master playback"
alias i="$MASTER 2dB+"
alias d="$MASTER 2dB-"
alias mute="echo \" Audio muted.\"; $MASTER mute"
alias play="echo \" Audio un-muted.\"; $MASTER unmute"
alias unmute="play"
alias stop="mute"
v () {
  amixer -q sset Master playback $1%
}
```

Comment: Regarding binding commands to keyboard shortcuts: it depends solely on our window manager how this is done.

Comment: Yes, the problem is not how to bind the commands but to make them work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first two aliases, it appears the +/- must go *after* the value to be treated as a relative change, instead of an absolute value [(amixer man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer%20%22amixer%20man%20page):

```
alias i="amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback +1db+"
alias d="amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback +1db-"
```

I would replace the last two (and their 8 assumed brethren) with a single shell function:

```
v () {
  amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback $i%
}
```

Comment: `alias d="amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback 1dB-"` works (note no plus sign), `alias i="amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback 1dB+"` does not work (nor with the first plus sign). Very strange!

Comment: @EmanuelBerg: Try escaping the `+` signs (prepend \\).

Comment: Sorry, same old. But: `amixer -c 0 -- sset Master playback 2dB+` works. I tested 3 and 4, they work as well. For some reason, it works to decrease by 1, but not increase by 1. To be a bug, it is a bit unlikely because it would be the first bug to be discovered. How about writing a function that increases by 3, and the decreases by 2? :)

Comment: I'm not aware of older versions, but as current, you can use command like this: `amixer -c 0 -- set Master 1dB+`